# determine correct place using homography matrix (AR)

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, emgucv

I use surf in emgu cv lib to detect and recgnize my object i need to insert 3d model in the place of this object i have the homography matrix what i want to know is how to get modelview matrix of sharpgl from this homography matrix .i want steps that can result me the correct modelview matrix where i can place the 3d object
any answer will help me 
thanks in advance

Comment: i find a solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342330/how-to-augment-cube-onto-a-specific-position-using-3x3-homography
but i don't know how to get intrinsic paramters(Camera Calibration)
please i need fast answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AForge.net. The author of that library did something very similar using glyphs and then inserting his own 3D model in place of the glyph. The library handles the 3d pose of the glyph and applies those to the 3d model.  The project can be found here

http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/gratf/

I dont know how you would do this same thing with Open CV and Emgu.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply calibrate your camera using Zhang's method to get camera matrices and then use H decomposition as described in the link you found.
To sum up:

1. Perform Classical checkboard corner detection (emgucv code [here](http://www.kclbot.com/academic/emgu-cv-c-tutorial-find-chess-board-corners/))
2. Increase corner detection accuracy to subpixel level invoking FindCornerSubPix() function
3. Finally use CameraCalibration.CalibrateCamera() to calculate the intrinsic camera parameters

Hope this helps